# How to create an average with turn around values

Tags: average

A compass value goes from 0...360°. Normal averaging routines generate a huge error, when the compass value transits from 359 to 0, or back.
I'm too stupid, creating an algo, which can handle this transition.

Comment: How do you *want* it to handle that transition?  The behavior, if not the implementation.  (Example(s) would be helpful here.)

Comment: I basically think of a moving avg of 10 samples, but for the example just 4. Say  I turn right: 340,345, 350, 355 [°] avg = 347.5; Then 345, 350,355,360 avg= 352.5, the problem occurs already here, if I use 0 instead of 360. avg would become 262.5; finally 350,355,0,5 avg should be 357.5 but becomes 177.5; last 0,5,10,15 avg= 7.5

Comment: Under what conditions should you use 360+x in the average instead of x?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here:

[Angle average](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Averages/Mean_angle#C.2B.2B)
I take no responsability for the content under this link.